# PHP String Concat help needed

Tags: php

I am new to PHP, 
And am creating a data string, which i have written like this.

```
$data = $product['id']. "/" . $product['name'] . "/" .$product['price'];
```

I don't know if there is another better way to create this String.

Comment: Hello. What do you feel as "worse" (wrt "better") in this way of doing things ?

Comment: I don't know if this good or bad is.

Comment: you can also use single quotes: http://www.sematopia.com/2007/08/php-double-quotes-vs-single-quotes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP can interpolate array values inside double quotes if they are surrounded with `{}`:

```
$data = "{$product['id']}/{$product['name']}/{$product['price']}";
```

If you remove the quotes around the keys you don't need the curly braces and it will become even simpler:

```
$data = "$product[id]/$product[name]/$product[price]";
```

Comment: I disagree on the readability. The OP solution is imho perfectly fine.

Comment: This is much more readable: $data = "$product[id]/$product[name]/$product[price]";

Comment: @Maris: Wouldn't not enclosing the key in quotes lead to an E_NOTICE error?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a perfectly fine way to concatenate strings in php.

Answer (score 1):

So simple task cannot be wrong. You can concatenate strings in any way you want.

I usually prefer same style as you wrote in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) for it, which has the advantage of giving a better overview:

```
sprintf('%d/%s/%f', $product['id'], $product['name'], $product['price']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way:

```
$data  = "Name";
$date .= $product['id'];
$date .= "AND etc..";
```

Comment: This is wors in a performance way and also wrong in that it will not create the same string as the example.